# Fonts with non-standard "normal" line-height

Tags: css, fonts

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#Values), the value of the `line-height` property keyword `normal`:

> Depends on the user agent. Desktop browsers (including Firefox) use a
>   default value of roughly 1.2, depending on the element's font-family.

Standard body text on a site I am working with is styled with a `line-height` value of `1.6` (or 1.6 times the font size) to give the text more breathing room and improve readability. With most fonts this is great, but while internationalizing the site I have discovered that some fonts have a `normal` value of much more than `1.2`. When the "relaxed" `line-height: 1.6` value is applied, it actually gets more compact and harder to read.

Having to set a different line-height value for each language and font rendered on our site (we support about a hundred) would be cumbersome. **Is there a way, either in pure CSS or perhaps by modifying the font itself, to avoid the need for font-specific overrides on our standard site styles?**

The specific font in question is NotoSansMyanmar, but I expect to hit the same issue with other non-Roman fonts.

The following screenshots show how Times New Roman gets more relaxed with `line-height: 1.6` compared to `normal` and Noto gets more compact.

---

[image: With line-height normal on both fonts]

---

[image: With line-height 1.6 on both fonts]

Comment: [Maybe this points you in the right direction?](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-lang) If not, you could always just create a sass mixin or function and include it since you say you deal with so many fonts.

Comment: I was unaware of this feature, there might be something here I can use.

Comment: Let me know how you proceed; as my clients diversify I would love to see how this pans out.

Comment: I think what we'll probably do is use a CSS custom property for our standard line heights, and when we're dealing with a font that needs more line-height, we'll override that property.